# DDD(ドメイン駆動設計)における、マスタ情報の扱い

Tags: ドメイン駆動設計, アーキテクチャ

DDDとクリーンアーキテクチャでシステムを設計しているのですが、マスタテーブルに永続化されているValueObjectの扱いについて困っています。

ProductEntity{id,name,price,rank}
があります。rankはpriceの値を元に決められます。
DB的にはランクテーブルがあり、基準価格とその基準でのランクを保持しています。
(例 0円以上はランクA、5000円以上はランクB、10000円以上はランクC)

既に永続化されている状態から、priceを元にrankを探すのはProductRepositoryが行えるので問題ありません。

問題となるのは、Productを生成するFactoryでランク情報が取得できない点です。
新規商品を追加する際に、外部からinputされる情報はnameとpriceのみです。

ユースケースではValueObjectであるRankを直接取得できないためProductEntityが生成できません。
RepositoryやServiceは外部のデータを引数に取ることはできない＝ドメインモデルを引数に取るということで、新規Entityを作成し、それを永続化するという部分が実装できません。

このような場合はなにかうまい実装方法があるのでしょうか？
それとも設計がおかしいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

クリーンアーキテクチャのルールに疎いせいか、何が制約になっているのかがいまいち掴みきれていませんが、私ならこんな風に設計するということで・・・

まず、Priceを元にRankを決定するのはドメインの知識なので、ドメインモデル化します。
ここではRankPolicyエンティティとしましょう。

```
RankPolicy
 + calculateRank(price: Price): Rank

RankPolicyRepository
 + get(): RankPolicy
```

まず先に、RankPolicyRepositoryからRankPolicyを取得しておきます。
そして、ProductFactoryにこのRankPolicyを渡して、ProductFactoryの中からRankPolicy#calculateRank()を呼び出し、ランクを求めます。